# Hot tub receptacle location

Tags: hot-tub

Can a 120v GFI receptacle be near a not tub?  The practical location of the receptacle that accepts the GFI plug for the hot tub is 2 feet from the tub. No one has any reason to stand inside the tub to reset the GFI (or hopefully smart enough). The receptacle is on a GFI breaker at the main panel so thats protected also..

Comment: "Smart enough" is the main concern.  Half of youtube is about people who should be, but aren't.  GFIs were made for those people, but would not want to trust my life that they work at the right time.

Comment: I understand! Even knowledgeable get caught up and do wrong .  I decided to locate the receptacle under the deck out of sight.  Its still accessible... but a PITA to get to.   Thanks

Comment: What do you plan on running on that outlet?  LED lights, radio/sound equipment? If no high power requirements...like an electric grill or something like that, an isolation transformer provides really good protection,   Small ones that can deliver 100 -200 watts aren't terrible expensive, but if you get into higher power needs, they can get very expensive.  Isolation transformers are required in Canada in bathrooms, enough for a cell phone charger or electric razor or electric toothbrush but certainly not nearly enough for a hair dryer.

Answer (score 2):

Since the circuit is supplied by a GFCI circuit breaker, an additional GFCI receptacle is not useful or helpful.  They will *both* trip, and trying to get them to reset will be no fun, and will lead to wasteful calls to electricians.

However, it should be noted that you can't put any old thing on a large 30-60A circuit.  If some "clever" person hung a 120V outlet off the main 30-60A hot tub circuit, that is a code violation.

The 120V receptacle within 6-20' of a hot tub can simply be an extension of outdoor receptacle circuits already existing on the house.

Answer (score 1):

Can't quote NEC specifics at the moment, but [this site](https://harrison-electric.com/Blog/entryid/225/planning-to-put-a-hot-tub-out-back-electrical-requirements-you-need-to-know) says:

> There must be at least one convenience receptacle between six and 20 feet from the inside wall of the hot tub.

and that sounds about right to me. You *want* to have a receptacle nearby - for all kinds of possible uses, but not within arm's reach **because water + electricity = danger**.

Note that quote is actually about a convenience receptacle. Your question is actually about powering the hot tub itself. I am pretty sure similar rules apply, though in the case of the hot tub itself it could be hard-wired instead of a receptacle, and in fact generally that would be preferable.

Obviously everything has to be GFCI protected that is any of:

- Outside
- Powering a hot tub
- Near a hot tub

and in this case you hit all three at the same time! But you do *not* want to have double-GFCI protection. That will result in a mess when the GFCI trips because *both will often trip at the same time*. So you really want GFCI back at the subpanel, with any receptacles near the hot tub:

- Not including a GFCI at the receptacle - i.e., avoid double-protection as it does not help
- At least 6 feet away - because even with GFCI, you just don't want to take that risk
- Weather-resistant

Comment: Nothing in NEC requires GFCI *receptacles*.  They require GFCI *protection* which can happen a number of ways. The linked website is wrong.  Quote edited to remove wrong part.

Comment: Thank you very much, your information answers ny questions.   There is a GFCI at the end of the hot tub cord and I still have the receptacle protected for times when it is used as a "convience"..  I appreciate your response.